# array or variable loses value when entering if/else statement

Tags: php, laravel

here is some of the code where I declared the values for $list.

```
$list['first_name']            = Request::input("first_name");
$list['last_name']             = Request::input("last_name");
```

when I use dd($list), it shows the value like in my [snipped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyXvt.png)

but when it enters this if else statement,

```
if($existing_customer)
{
     $customer_id            = $existing_customer->customer_id;
}
else
{
    dd($list);
    $insert_customer["first_name"]     = ($list['first_name'] == "undefined" ? "John" : ucfirst($list['first_name']));
    $insert_customer["last_name"]      = ($list['last_name'] == "undefined" ? "Doe" : ucfirst($list['last_name']));
}
```

this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiMaj.png).

here is the photo of my function, if it could help.
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Bsr.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akyLH.png)

```
public function import_submit()
{
    $data                       = Self::get_initial_settings();
    /* INITIALIZE AND CAPTURE DATA */
    $shop_id                    = $this->user_info->shop_id;
    $sponsor                    = Tbl_mlm_slot::where("slot_no", Request::input("sponsor"))->where("shop_id", $shop_id)->value("slot_id");
    $placement                  = Tbl_mlm_slot::where("slot_no", Request::input("placement"))->where("shop_id", $shop_id)->value("slot_id");

    /* POSITIONING DATA */
    $slot_sponsor               = $sponsor;
    $slot_placement             = $placement;
    $slot_position              = strtolower(Request::input("position"));


    /* SLOT GENERATION */
    $membership_package_id      = Request::input("package_number");


    /* JUST ADD TO SLOT IF EXISTING CUSTOMER */


    if(Request::input("date_created") == "undefined")
    {
        $slot_date_created      = date("Y-m-d h:i");
    }
    else
    {
        $slot_date_created      = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Request::input("date_created")));
    }

    $existing_customer          = Tbl_customer::where("shop_id", $shop_id)->where("email", Request::input("email"))->first();

    $list['first_name']            = Request::input("first_name");
    $list['last_name']             = Request::input("last_name");
    $list['email']                 = Request::input("email");
    $list['slot_no']               = Request::input("slot_no");
    $list['password']              = Request::input("password");
    $list['birthday']              = Request::input("birthday");
    $list['contact']               = Request::input("contact_number");
    $list['gender']                = Request::input("gender");

    dd($list); <---- first run of the function, I put one here


    if($existing_customer)
    {
        $customer_id            = $existing_customer->customer_id;
    }
    else
    {
        dd($list); <--- for the second run of the function, to check what happens to my $list
        $insert_customer["shop_id"]        = $shop_id;
        $insert_customer["first_name"]     = ($list['first_name'] == "undefined" ? "John" : ucfirst($list['first_name']));
        $insert_customer["last_name"]      = ($list['last_name'] == "undefined" ? "Doe" : ucfirst($list['last_name']));

        $insert_customer["email"]          = ($list['email'] == "undefined" ? "dummy@gmail.com" : $list['email']);
        $insert_customer["ismlm"]          = 1;
        $insert_customer["mlm_username"]   = $list['slot_no'];
        $insert_customer["password"]       = ($list['password'] == "undefined" ? Crypt::encrypt(randomPassword()) : Crypt::encrypt($list['password']));
        $insert_customer["created_date"]   = $slot_date_created;
        $insert_customer["b_day"]          = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($list['birthday']));
        $insert_customer["birthday"]       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($list['birthday']));
        $insert_customer["contact"]        = $list['contact'];
        $insert_customer["gender"]         = strtolower($list['gender']);

        $customer_id = Tbl_customer::insertGetId($insert_customer);

        /* Insert Customer Address */
        $address_purpose[0] = "permanent";
        $address_purpose[1] = "billing";
        $address_purpose[2] = "shipping";

        foreach ($address_purpose as $key => $value) 
        {
            $insert_customer_address["customer_id"] = $customer_id;
            $insert_customer_address["country_id"] = 420;
            $insert_customer_address["customer_state"] = "";
            $insert_customer_address["customer_city"] = "";
            $insert_customer_address["customer_zipcode"] = "";
            $insert_customer_address["customer_street"] = Request::input("address");
            $insert_customer_address["purpose"] = $value;
            $insert_customer_address["archived"] = 0;
            $insert_customer_address["created_at"] = Carbon::now();
            $insert_customer_address["updated_at"] = Carbon::now();

            Tbl_customer_address::insert($insert_customer_address);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't really see where I went wrong as the values went null just because they entered that if/else statement.

Comment: Why don't you put the codes inside the text?

Comment: Sorry sir, but my function is kinda long, but the codes I put in text is essentially where something goes wrong... I think

Comment: Select your code.Copy them.Paste them into the editor.Again select your code in the editor. Press { } button in the editor.You will see it's working fine and there is no problem :)

Comment: there sir, updated

Comment: first confirm do you get value from this Request::input("first_name"); ?

is this code in laravel ?

Comment: Where and how did you _initialize_ this variable `$list` …?

Comment: @ashishkumar yes sir , i can get the value of that code, and yes it is in laravel. I'm gonna go edit its tag to include laravel

Comment: @CBroe I initialized it just like this:  $list['first_name']  = Request::input("first_name");

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($list);` please? Just so that we can make sure it is not some sort of bug with `dd`.

Comment: @CBroe I did a var_dump, but still shows the same kind of thing, just in a different format sir

Comment: So if you make two debug outputs within the same script instance, one directly before the if, and one first thing in the else branch - you get two different outputs? Can you please edit the exact locations where you are making the debug outputs into the full code of your function above, so that we see 1:1 what you are executing?

Comment: @CBroe I updated the code above, and the place where I put dd() is also where I used var_dump

Comment: [Laravel's `dd()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-dd) is named for "dump and die", i.e. it dumps the variable and then ends the execution. This means your two outputs you showed cannot be from the same invocation of the script. Use `var_dump()` instead to get the content of the variable at different positions in the script, without stopping execution.

Comment: @KarstenKoop what i meant with the 2 dd()'s is where I put them from two executions to see what happened sir

Comment: Yes, as I said: You are looking at two different executions.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Sorry for the late reply, I think I found now what happens. Thanks a lot sir!